# DynamoDB table design: one attribute with nested json or multiple attributes

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

When reading AWS dynamoDB documentation, i saw that it didn't recommend creating multiple tables. But when we put json formatted data in DynamoDB tables, should be create an attribute with many levels (such as 10) of nested json content or multiple attributes with less levels? I guess it's case by case. But what i would like to know is the general rule when designing dynamoDB tables. After reading AWS documentations, I am still confused so I am posting question here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although there aren't any standard rules, the best approach I see as a guideline is to review the;

- DynamoDB features (Keys, Indexes)
- Limits
- Pricing model

before designing the tables. In your case, the tradeoff in having attributes is that;

- Possibility to index for efficient queries (Better performance avoiding scans,  Low utilization of IOPS resulting lower costs).
- Project only the required attributes.
- But limits the flexibility in modeling.

On the other hand having nested JSON attributes allows to;

- More attributes and flexibility in structure.
- More towards document structure moving from Key-Value nature.
- But limits efficient queries of deep nested attributes.
- More costly in terms of IOPS since entire nested attribute needs to be retrieved even to read a nested attribute (which also increases the cost).

Since it is also possible to have Keys, Primitive Attributes and Nested attributes in one table, it would be better use them in combination, case by case rather sticking with one model.